# ajax-enabled wcf service, how to pass in parameters to a method in the service implementation through url

Tags: wcf, jquery, parameter-passing

When I try to use UriTemplate, this exception take place.
System.InvalidOperationException: Endpoints using 'UriTemplate' cannot be used with 'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior'.
And I have no idea how to pass in parameters through url any more..
Any help?

Comment: How are you hosting the service?  I'm guessing you're calling it via javascript?

Comment: Yes, I am calling using jquery .ajax

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - there's some jQuery magic you can take advantage of to make this much easier (see the link and sample project I refer to below).

Also, make sure to host your service using the [WebScriptServiceHostFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.webscriptservicehostfactory.aspx).

Something like:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#"
    Service="ServiceContractName"
    Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory" %>
```

... if you're hosting the service in IIS.

Take a look at this article:

[Creating a WCF Service for JSON](http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2010/02/01/Creating-a-WCF-Service-for-JSON.aspx)

I realize that you're not asking about JSON, but the sample code he provides demonstrates how to pass parameters in your request and response for your service method calls.

I suggest reading the article, and downloading the excellent sample and going through it carefully, attempting to understand what he's doing and why.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, I noticed that we could add to .svc file ServiceHost directive the Factory attribute, and I remembered that **WebScriptServiceHostFactory** has something to do with ajax. Is this practice using factory pattern and what is behind the magic behind the **Factory attribute**?? I was able to deal with passing parameters using post verb by the way.